# Storage issues with o-phthaldialdehyde (OPA) reagent used to derivatize amino acids

Tags: experimental-chemistry, chromatography

I have made up an o-phthaldialdehyde (OPA) reagent according to [Handbook of HPLC page 715](https://books.google.com/books?id=4mj_DArD5n0C&pg=PA715&lpg=PA715&dq=handbook%20of%20hplc%20opa%20derivatization&source=bl&ots=FSOz79VpQF&sig=oq4vpcMvK5SEGz3Xo3FS9wgwR_8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAGoVChMI0uqS55mfxwIVip6ACh2TPQDM#v=onepage&q=handbook%20of%20hplc%20opa%20derivatization&f=false) that will be used to derivatize amino acids before an HPLC run. There is no information given on reagent storage, but the OPA crystals themselves must be stored in the fridge. However, storing this reagent in the fridge causes clear crystals to form that cannot be redissolved into solution. Has anyone had similar issues? Is it possible to store this reagent at room temperature without having the reagent lose strength?

Comment: Most protocols I have seen call for freshly preparing OPA solutions immediately before use, or perhaps for storing the OPA solution for at most one day.